# (Internal testing) This app isn’t available for your device because it was made from an older version of android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-play, target-sdk

I have published app in playstore for internal testing with targetSdkVersion 33. All good until I have tried to test and I downloaded it to my Android phone and it says **"This app isn’t available for your device because it was made from an older version of android"**
I have Android 12.

any one have any idea about this issue? and why this is happenning?
Should work for Android 13.

[image]

My build.gradle

```html
 compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.portlmedia.streets"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        buildConfigField "String", "WEBVIEW_URL", "\"https://streets.portlmedia.com\""
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a missing required feature but the error message is wrong (this happens).

Try:

```
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
```